# Reduce time querying SQL table

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I have a user form that runs a query and updates an object in the userform.
Every time the user clicks a button the query is rerun.

Can I open the connection when I initialize the form so I don't have to open it each time the user clicks the button?
Will this remove the slight delay I'm getting after the click?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the main program?  (Access, Excel, etc.)

Comment: The userform is running on top of excel, though I'm not actually using the excel it self.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use connection pool so that openned connections can be reused

Comment: Can you explain what connection pool is?  I'm embarrassed to say I've never heard of it.